Can anyone identify this black stuff in our attic?
My parents are in the process of trying to sell our old house and my dad found this black, crumbly residue on our wooden beams in the attic. It’s a very small, tight space. It’s isolated to two beams and the rest are completely clear. There’s no odor (maybe a VERY SLIGHT metallic smell) and it has a texture almost like cracker crumbs. It scrapes right off the wood. Any ideas?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nJbjvIX2D6oRQZ6hZxOMpXC5OTBmpW3_/view

Probably dried sap, but showing it after scraping rather than before makes that more of a guess than it would be from an in-place photo.
